# how can i remove those numbers

Tags: java

this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("N:");   
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
float n = in.nextFloat();
float a,b,c,d;
a = n/1000;
b= n/100%10;
c = n/10%10;
d = n%10;

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
```

[image]

and I want to remove those numbers. I'm newbie :) help me pls

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to try to find the digits of a 4 digit integer number.

Therefore, it makes no sense to use `float` variables. Use `int`.

```
int n = in.nextInt();
int a,b,c,d;
a = n/1000;
b= n/100%10;
c = n/10%10;
d = n%10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.Round(number,2) 2 decimals in this case.

Or, you want the number without decimals? If yes, use `int`